# pm2 process crashed on server. it gives an error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, pm2

suddenly i received this error in my terminal.

```
[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
```

I have used pm2 for it. And one of my process is restart autometically.
Can you tell me why such happen?
Or is there any other solutions for it?
Please suggest me for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can increase the size of memory restart by doing below things

```
pm2 start process.js --max-memory-restart 2G (newer pm2 version)
pm2 start process.js --max-stack-size=65000" (older pm2 version)
```

And add below lines in your node.js file.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
 console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
 console.log(err.stack);
});
```

for more detail : [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management)

Comment: I am getting `error: unknown option `--max-stack-size'` for the second option